# Plotting 75000 points on a rich Scatter Chart with Tooltips

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I could post some code here but the title of the question is exactly what the problem is.

My `chart.destroy()` takes a lot of time with 75000 points. Each point has a tooltip too (tooltip used is Highcharts' own tooltip)

Also, drawing a new chart using `new Highcharts.Chart({ ...options...})` also takes a lot of time.

Has anyone worked with these many data points with Highcharts? If yes, how did you manage to keep it working smoothly. A 4-5 second lag is fine but I'm getting 30 second delays in rendering the chart. GC event in the Timeline shows a lot of data being garbage collected as well. I sense I don't have a solution but I'm desperately looking for any clues.

Thanks!

Comment: Here you can find example for Highcharts on Canvas with 50k of scatter points: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/az37W/ - however without tooltip, since tooltip is mainly the culprit of that performance issues.

Comment: I have seen that before, but it doesn't help me because I need tooltips. thanks for tip, thought :)

Comment: You know, the main problem with performance in Highcharts is with a) markers b) tooltip, since it's using the most of resources of your machine. You want scatter (markers) and tooltip, then.. good luck ;) Anyway, how would be possible to read that kind of scatter with 75 000 of points? As user I must say it will be terrible.

Comment: @PawełFus totally agree with the (non)user-friendliness of such a tool. But, sometimes, and I repeat, sometimes, you just aren't the boss on these things

Comment: I understand. But sometimes programmers are limited to resources of PC's and there's not much we can do about this. At least, not in JS.

Answer (score 1):

The performance bottleneck lies with the amount of data that needs to be in memory to represent each point in your data set. Since you want tooltips, each point will have to store it's value as a string in memory; therefore you will need at least 75,000 objects in memory not including the cost of highcharts itself. The reason why highcharts can display 75k scatter plot in a significantly shorter amount of time (without tooltips) is that it samples the output and displays an estimation without any interactivity of the points.

http://jsfiddle.net/5haL91vf/1/

For demonstration purposes, I'm using a library called ZingChart and using the render type as canvas to improve performance with large datasets. With tooltips enabled, I'm able to render 75k in just a hair under 15s on my computer (obviously computer dependent). But as you can see theres no real value to a scatter plot when the visualization density exceeds the pixel density.

Simple setup with timing:

```
 startTime = Date.now();
 zingchart.render({
    id:'zc',
    width: 1000,
    height: 700,
    output: "canvas",
    data:myChart
});

zingchart.bind('zc', 'complete', function(){
    alert((Date.now() - startTime)/1000 + " seconds");
});
```

Comment: Just to be clear, 75k without tooltip works quite fast: http://jsfiddle.net/az37W/17/ - less than 1sec. And with tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/az37W/22/ - 12sec (of course, depends on pc, as you said, but your example took me 45secs to render?).